# Why does my MapReduce job get stuck at Map 0% Reduce 0%?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm testing a filesystem on Hadoop 3.3.1, and every time I run a MapReduce job it gets stuck at "map 0% reduce 0%", meanwhile everything (containers, applications, etc.) is stuck at "RUNNING". Does anybody know why? Or what should I do to find out what the real problem is?

Here's the console output:

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.1.jar wordcount wordcount/input wordcount/output
2022-02-27 15:17:21,136 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.1.1:8032
2022-02-27 15:17:21,731 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 5
2022-02-27 15:17:21,761 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:5
2022-02-27 15:17:22,064 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1645945958451_0002
2022-02-27 15:17:22,064 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2022-02-27 15:17:22,241 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-02-27 15:17:22,242 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-02-27 15:17:22,498 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1645945958451_0002
2022-02-27 15:17:22,539 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1645945958451_0002/
2022-02-27 15:17:22,540 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1645945958451_0002
2022-02-27 15:17:27,644 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1645945958451_0002 running in uber mode : false
2022-02-27 15:17:27,646 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Here is my `yarn-site.xml` configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
     <value>99.0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.madfs.impl</name>
    <value>madfs.AbsXxxFS</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

My `mapred-site.xml` configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>master:10020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/xyz/hadoop-3.3.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/xyz/hadoop-3.3.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/xyz/hadoop-3.3.1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

P.s. there's no ERROR nor WARNING in the logs dumped by ResourceManager and NodeManager. And the states of `RMAppAttemptImpl`, `RMAppImpl`, `RMContainerImpl`, `ContainerMonitorImpl` and `ApplicationImpl` are all stuck at `RUNNING`.

Here's the ResourceManager log [hadoop-resourcemanager.out](https://pastebin.com/dyJ4weRp), and here's the NodeManager log [hadoop-nodemanager.out](https://pastebin.com/gDvGuBbX).

---

Update:

The problem seems to be the application failed to preempt the required resources...

The app status I got using `yarn app -status <appId>`:

```
Application Report : 
        Application-Id : application_1645945958451_0003
        Application-Name : QuasiMonteCarlo
        Application-Type : MAPREDUCE
        User : xyz
        Queue : default
        Application Priority : 0
        Start-Time : 1645976932440
        Finish-Time : 0
        Progress : 0%
        State : RUNNING
        Final-State : UNDEFINED
        Tracking-URL : http://master:45299
        RPC Port : 46709
        AM Host : master
        Aggregate Resource Allocation : 997310 MB-seconds, 486 vcore-seconds
        Aggregate Resource Preempted : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds
        Log Aggregation Status : DISABLED
        Diagnostics : 
        Unmanaged Application : false
        Application Node Label Expression : <Not set>
        AM container Node Label Expression : <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
        TimeoutType : LIFETIME  ExpiryTime : UNLIMITED  RemainingTime : -1seconds
```

Also, only 1 container is allocated to this job, does that has anything to do with the problem?

Comment: `The url to track the job`... Open the yarn UI and look how much resources are available vs what you're requesting

Comment: Please edit the question itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks! But I get 502 Bad Gateway when I curl the website... Where else can I check the available resources?

Comment: Neither of those are what I was asking for. Open the web browser to the YARN UI

Comment: If you get a bad gateway, then you have some extra networking setup to do. `http://192.168.1.1:8000` should work without any error

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried but got a 502 Bad Gateway when I visit the YARN website :(

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks I would try later!

Comment: You can use something like `yarn -applicationId application_1645945958451_0002` as well, but I don't know how to get the information you need

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I managed to see the application status and it seemed like the app didn't get any memory and v-core, (the output is updated in the question). I tried googling it but didn't get any solution. Do you know why this happens? @OneCricketeer

Comment: You mean `Resource Preempted` line? I don't think that's saying anything about allocated resources or how much is actually available for YARN to use. More specifically, you should check the Nodemanager processes are healthy; the logs you provided above should be in the question itself and the links are no longer available

Comment: Oops I created another paste and updated the Nodemanager log link in the question. I checked the `yarn top` and no node is UNHEALTHY, also there were remaining memory and v-cores in the queues shown in `yarn top` :( @OneCricketeer